# when I cliked any USA state map the chart filter on another section in fusionchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fusioncharts

I am using USA/state map fusionchart so when I clicked any USA state it will trigger a new bar chart in another section and vice versa the data filter each time when I clicked any chart either world map or bar chart I know we can use event listener but here my concern is how data filter in another section suppose when I clicked any chart other chart data also filter or trigger.Below I have attached screenshot where left side image i.e USA Map when I cliked any state other bar chart data will trigger on right side[image]

```
const dataset = [
  {
    id: "HI",
    value: "3189000",
    //link: "j-drillDownState-HI|Hawaii",
    link: "Detailed/TotalSales.html",
    alpha: "100",

    usehovercolor: "1",
    showtooltip: "1",
  },
  {
    id: "DC",
    value: "2879000",
    link: "Detailed/TotalSales.html",
  },
  {
    id: "MD",
    value: "33592000",
    link: "j-drillDownState-MD|Maryland",
  },
  {
    id: "DE",
    value: "4607000",
    link: "j-drillDownState-DE|Delaware",
  },
  {
    id: "RI",
    value: "4890000",
    link: "j-drillDownState-RI|Rhode Island",
  },
  {
    id: "WA",
    value: "34927000",
    link: "j-drillDownState-WA|Washington",
  },]
const chartConfigs = {
  type: "maps/usa", // The chart type
  id: "data-plot-click-mouse-event",
  width: "500", // Width of the chart
  height: "400", // Height of the chart
  dataFormat: "json", // Data type
  dataSource: {
    // Map Configuration
    chart: {
      numbersuffix: "%",
      includevalueinlabels: "1",
      labelsepchar: ": ",
      entityFillHoverColor: "#FFF9C4",
      theme: "fusion",
      color: "red",
    },
    events: {
      dataPlotClick: function (e) {
        var infoElem = document.getElementById("infolbl");
        var index = e.data.dataIndex;
        infoElem.innerHTML =
          "The average value from <b>" +
          e.data.startText +
          "</b> to <b>" +
          e.data.endText +
          "</b> is <b>" +
          Math.round(e.data.binValue * 100) / 100 +
          "k</b>";
      },
    },

   
    events: {
      // Attach to beforeInitialize
      initialized: function () {
        console.log("Initialized mychart...");
      },
    },

    
    data: dataset,
  },
};
class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      actualValue: "Hover on the plot to see the value along with the label",
      message: "Hover on the plot to see the value along with the label",
    };

    this.dataplotrollover = this.dataplotrollover.bind(this);
    this.dataplotrollout = this.dataplotrollout.bind(this);
  }

  
  dataplotrollover(eventObj, dataObj) {
    this.setState({
      message: [
        "You are currently hovering over ",
        <strong>{dataObj.categoryLabel}</strong>,
        " whose value is ",
        <strong>{dataObj.displayValue}</strong>,
      ],
    });
  }

  
  dataplotrollout(eventObj, dataObj) {
    this.setState({
      message: this.state.actualValue,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactFC
          {...chartConfigs}
          fcEvent-dataplotRollOver={this.dataplotrollover}
          fcEvent-dataplotRollOut={this.dataplotrollout}
        />

        {console.log("map", this.state.message)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map
```

Answer (score 1):

In FusionCharts you can easily update the chart/ map data on triggering the respective click events . For charts,  you need to use the "dataplotClick" event API and for maps use the "entityClick " ëvent API. In the event callbacks you need to use the "setJSONData()" method to update the chart/ map data.

Reference sample in react: https://codesandbox.io/s/setjsondata-sample-wojt5?file=/src/index.js

Documentation Links:-

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods#setJSONData

Thanks,

Srishti Jaiswal

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below dashboard where clicking on a map entity updates other chart's data. You can also download it's source code for reference. You have to implement the business logic accordingly.

Documentation Links:-

Dashboard: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dashboards/wealth-management-dashboard

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events